Azure function flex consumption plan bash execute
In azure function .NET 8 isolated worker on linux flex consumption plan, is it possible to execute bash script in code by invoking .sh file stored in project?

Provide your script.

Check if below answer helps @salttoinjury.

Follow below steps to achieve your requirement:
Create a .sh file under scripts folder in root directory.
./Scripts/myscript.sh:
#!/bin/bash
echo  "Hello from myscript.sh!"
echo  "This is a test file created by the script."  >  /tmp/testfile.txt
cat  /tmp/testfile.txt
exit  0

Use below function code in .NET 8.0 Isolated Azure functions to execute bash script by invoking .sh file in the function code.
Code Snippet:
[Function("Function1")]
public IActionResult Run([HttpTrigger(AuthorizationLevel.Anonymous, "get", "post")] HttpRequest req)
{
    _logger.LogInformation("C# HTTP trigger function processed a request.");
    _logger.LogInformation(Directory.GetCurrentDirectory());
    string scriptPath = Path.Combine("/home", "site", "wwwroot", "scripts", "myscript.sh");
    
    if (!File.Exists(scriptPath))
    {
        _logger.LogError($"Script file not found at {scriptPath}");         
    }

    var startInfo = new ProcessStartInfo
    {
        FileName = "/bin/bash",
        Arguments = scriptPath,
        RedirectStandardOutput = true,
        RedirectStandardError = true,
        UseShellExecute = false,
        CreateNoWindow = true
    };

    try
    {
        using (var process = Process.Start(startInfo))
        {
            if (process != null)
            {
                string output = process.StandardOutput.ReadToEnd();
                string error =  process.StandardError.ReadToEnd();

                _logger.LogInformation($"Output: {output}");
                if (!string.IsNullOrEmpty(error))
                {
                    _logger.LogError($"Error: {error}");
                }

                 process.WaitForExitAsync();
            }
        }
    }
    catch (Exception ex)
    {
        _logger.LogError($"An error occurred while executing the script: {ex.Message}");
    }

    return new OkObjectResult("Success!");
}

Deploy the function to Azure function App with flex consumption plan.
Console Output:
Run the function and you will be able to execute the script using Azure function. Check the invocation logs for detailed output as below.
2024-12-13T10:52:30Z   [Information]   Executing 'Functions.Function1' (Reason='This function was programmatically called via the host APIs.', Id=58d00ce3-f7cb-4dad-9f2c-479e622cbed4)
2024-12-13T10:52:30Z   [Information]   C# HTTP trigger function processed a request.
2024-12-13T10:52:30Z   [Information]   /tmp/functions\standby\wwwroot
2024-12-13T10:52:30Z   [Information]   Output: Hello from myscript.sh!
This is a test file created by the script.
2024-12-13T10:52:30Z [Information] Executing OkObjectResult, writing value of type 'System.String'.
2024-12-13T10:52:30Z [Information] Executed 'Functions.Function1' (Succeeded, Id=c726dfa3-52f2-43b1-8121-5184c01cf74b, Duration=20ms)

